# Большие числа в golang

Tags: golang

Всем привет. Необходимо слагать, вычитать, умножать и делить числа больше чем 2^20 какие с этим могут возникнуть трудности? Каким трудности можно преодолеть? В какую сторону копать чтобы делать это правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Трудности могут появиться при попытке объявить переменную, превышающую 18 квинтиллионов:

```
var distance uint64 = 24e18 // Ошибка: 24000000000000000000 overflows uint64
```

Чтобы обойти эту проблему можно задействовать математику чисел с плавающей запятой.

Также в `go` есть замечательный пакет [big](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big). Его можно использовать для реально больших чисел, которые не влазят в `int64`.

Пакет `big` предоставляет три типа данных:

- `big.Int` - для крупных целых чисел, когда 18 квинтиллионов недостаточно;
- `big.Float` - для вещественных чисел с плавающей запятой производной точности;
- `big.Rat` для дробей вроде 1/3.

---

Тут можно ознакомиться более подробно и с примерами:
https://golangify.com/big-numbers